# how to get multiple values from textfield inside a for loop and recive it in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, textfield

im pretty bginner at java , what i want to do is user gonna say how much numbers he will input so i save this number in a varieabale for ex: he wants to input 5 numbers so int x= 5;
then i want to recicve thoses 5 numbers that he will input in array, 
so i used for loop  to take all those numbers that he will input and save it in my array , but when i run the program and enter the first value the loop take only the first value and finished , so it dosent give me the chance to enter the rest of numbers .

```
public class Cuentafacil extends Application  {

    int numero_gastos;
    int b;


  @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) 
    {
        Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
        Label label=new Label("cuantos gastos tienes hoy ");
        Button Agregar=new Button("Listo");
        TextField nrgastos = new TextField();
        TextField nrgastos2=new TextField();
        Label label2=new Label();
Agregar.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
        {

          numero_gastos= Integer.parseInt(nrgastos.getText());
           root.getChildren().remove(Agregar);
           root.getChildren().remove(nrgastos);
           label.setText("Comiezna a poner los gastos");
           Agregar.setText("Agregar");

           root.getChildren().add(nrgastos2);
           root.getChildren().add(Agregar);


           nrgastos2.setPromptText("entra un gasto");
           nrgastos2.setTranslateX(160);
           nrgastos2.setTranslateY(50);
           int [] w = new int[numero_gastos];




            Agregar.setOnAction((ActionEvent s)->
            {
              b=Integer.parseInt(nrgastos2.getText());
             for (int x=0;x<numero_gastos;x++)
         {
             try{

         w[x]=b;
           nrgastos2.nextWord();

         nrgastos2.clear();


             }
             catch (Exception f)
             {
             System.out.println("here is the problem");
             }
         }

            System.out.println(IntStream.of(w).sum());

            });


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a `Scanner` for the text field string ans then store the elements in the array like this:

```
Scanner numReader = new Scanner(nrgastos.getText());
int [] w = new int[numero_gastos];

for (int i = 0; i < numero_gastos; i++) {
    w[i] = numReader.nextInt();
}

numReader.close();
```